# Using regular expression?

Tags: regex, shell, ksh

I have two data testing12334 which can be written as

```
testing[0-9]*$
```

in regular expression then I have testing33ab_1abckd which I can write as

```
testing[0-9][a-z][_][0-9][a-z].
```

I am trying to make one reg exp that works for both. Struggling any insight?

UPDATE: in shell(.ksh)

Comment: In your second example, your regex does not match the text. It's not clear what you're trying to match. My guess is that you mean `testing[0-9]+[a-z]+_[0-9]+[a-z]+`, which is not what the answers currently given are going to match. Then again, you might mean `testing[0-9a-z]+_[0-9a-z]+` or maybe just `testing[0-9a-z_]+`. You should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\btesting\w+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/1)

Or in shell you can use equivalent:

```
grep -E '\btesting[[:alnum:]_]+\b'
```

Comment: You didn't mention `ksh` in question but yes it will work with `grep -E`

Comment: That doesn't seem equivalent at all. It will match `testingX` for example

Comment: echo "$a" | grep "^testing\w+\b*$"
awk: warning: escape sequence `\w' treated as plain `w'
 getting error..

Comment: You can use: `grep -E '\btesting[[:alnum:]_]+\b'`

Comment: isn't their easier way?
[A-Z0-9]([0-9][A-Z][_][0-9][A-Z])
by this [A-Z0-9] I mean, start with either num or character

Comment: In shell `[[:alnum:]]` means either alphabet or number.

Comment: echo "$a"| awk -v str=$a '$2 ~ "^" str "[:alnum:]([0-9][A-Z][_][0-9][A-Z])*"

or

echo "$a" | grep "^$a[:alnum:]([a-z][_][0-9][a-z])*$"

doesnt work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61445/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kyle).

Answer (score 0):

Make the suffix part optional

```
testing[0-9]*([a-z][_][0-9][a-z]+)?$
```

In basic regular expressions (e.g. traditional `grep` and `sed`), you need to backslash the metacharacters. For extended regular expression syntax (basically `grep -E` and most everything newer than that, save for Emacs) this should work as-is.

Comment: I want if either could start with 0-9 or a-z

Comment: I just copy/pasted your allegedly working regex. I don't understand your additional requirements. What's testing1**? What's "either"?

Comment: I added the missing wildcard after `testing[0-9]` but the rest will have to be specified better.